# IIS Express change server to autostart, not on first demand

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-express

Visual Studio uses IIS express

**I want server to load data on start not on first http request.**

Settings are located in [solutiondir].vs\config

If I paste those attributes and then run by F5:

```
serviceAutoStartEnabled="true" serviceAutoStartProvider="ApplicationPreload"
```

xml

```
<site name="DesignHubSite" id="4" serverAutoStart="true">
  <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" serviceAutoStartEnabled="true" serviceAutoStartProvider="ApplicationPreload" physicalPath="C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHubVisualStudio\DesignHub\DesignHubSite" />
  </application>
  <bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54520:localhost" />
  </bindings>
</site>
```

I get this error:

> Error occurs "Process with Id of 6864 is not running"

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this configuration? Maybe you want to run on a Local IIS instance instead of IIS Express.

Comment: @Jasen I think using express which is already in VS is less complicated

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `serviceAutoStartEnabled` and `serviceAutoStartProvider` are attributes of the `<application />` element not `<virtualDirectory />`.

You can verify this by running:

```
iisexpress.exe /config:[path_to_applicationhost.config] /siteid:[site_id_in_applicationhost.config]
```

You'll see an error similar to the following:

```
Filename: \\?\[path_to_applicationhost.config]
Line number: [line_number]
Error: Unrecognized attribute 'serviceAutoStartEnabled'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

in application pool i have set startMode="AlwaysRunning" for worker 'Clr4IntegratedAppPool'

other changes are not requiered

now it works as intended

Comment: are you sure? because according to this https://forums.iis.net/t/1181129.aspx it is not possible with IIS Express